# Exposing service Configuration data at client side

Tags: javascript, meteor, ionic-framework

In my meteor application, I am using Service Configuration package to store auth0 configuration

Current behaviour of service package is its publish all auth0 credentials at client side we want to restrict to access service configuration setting details to client side.

Please help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it how to resolve this.This is for who face same issue in future.

Here: https://github.com/mitiaptest/login_demo/blob/0391d5f17eefd4f226fe64741c000e793d615f4a/server/server.js#L7

In Meteor, the publication publishes everything except a field named exactly secret: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/7b53281af6f074aa18b11db4931f2c45d54b2d83/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L696

We have to rename clientSecret field to secret.